# Debugging Symfony2 Console Commands with XDebug and PHPStorm

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

How should I configure PHPStorm so that I can trace my code using XDebug when running console commands?

I know I have the debug configuration correct, because I can debug web requests and trace the code.  I can also trace regular php command line scripts as long as I set an environment variable like this:

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=my-xdebug"
```

However, I am unable to trace/debug Symfony2 console commands (those run with `app/console bundle:console_command`).  PhpStorm sees the connection, however, it can't seem to locate the code that is being run.  I know my file mapping is correct because web requests work flawlessly.

Is this possible?

Comment: Enable logging from xdebug side and see what file it is running ... and then see if your mappings are correct.

Answer (score 26):

You should provide `SERVER_NAME` and `SERVER_PORT`. also you should enable `xdebug.remote_autostart`. Try this:

```sh
SERVER_PORT=<Your port> SERVER_NAME='<Your server> php \
    -dxdebug.remote_autostart=On app/console test
```

Comment: `php -dxdebug.remote_autostart=On app/console my:cmd` works. Thanks

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly , you should check this as the working answer ;)

Comment: @tom10271 you are the real MVP

Comment: FYI, the modern day version if this is `php -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes bin/console my:cmd`

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have enabled xdebug inside php.ini CLI version not only apache/cgi php.ini.

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
```

Comment: you should also add `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` and be sure that your mappings are correct in the debug configuration of the IDE

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting to try following BASH helper command:
https://github.com/torinaki/phpdebug-cli

`phpdebug` mostly autodetects all required configurations and you will not require to provide environment variables.

Just run:

```
phpdebug app/console bundle:console_command
```